# How can I print a long line in realtime in python?

Tags: python, batch-file, printing, subprocess

I am using a subprocess in my python script to open a `.bat` file. This `.bat` file generates very long lines that I would like to print to the console in realtime.

The problem is that these lines are sometimes very long so that they don't fit in the buffer. What can I do to print these lines anyway? Is it possible to print word by word instead if line by line?

Here is what I do:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("testfile.bat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("\r\n") # Some basic setup (simulated keypress)
p.stdin.close() 

# The actual print loop
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
        line = line.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
        print(line)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove this line, it's not needed:

```
line = line.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
```

And if you want to print word by word do this:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    for word in line.split():
        print(word)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: and how do define `line` then?

Comment: What do you mean? `line` is already defined, it's the iteration variable in the loop, and you don't have to do anything additional: it's already a line!

Comment: I get `Undefined variable: line`. And the iteration variable is `word`!

Comment: your answer is super confusing. what code is your solution? this is not working `for word in line.split(): print(word)`. Please, post a working solution, otherwise I cannot accept your answer

Comment: @user2426316 I assumed you were a bit more familiar with the language, sorry. I updated my answer with the complete code

Comment: @user2426316 you're welcome! and again, sorry about the first explanation, it wasn't clear enough. cheers!